# How can i post a variable equal to the only "style = 'display: block'" dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have 6 dropdown menus in a class called `.receiver` and only one will be visible based on the selection of the `#type1` dropdown menu.  Depending on the current value of the `#type` menu, the appropriate `.receiver` will be displayed.  I want to post the value of the only `.receiver` dropdown menu with the display set to "block".  Is there a selector I can use to do this? I tried to just get the `Program Glitch` to work by creating the `user_receiver` variable and assigning it the value of the `Program Glitch` menu on change but it doesn't work.

Here is my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var user_receiver;
  $("#type1").change(function() {
    $('#IT1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Operations1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Logistics1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#CustomerService1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Buyers1').css('display', 'none');
    var type = $("#type1").val();
    if (type == 'Program Glitch') {
      $('#IT1').css('display', 'block');
      user_receiver = ('#IT').val();
      document.write(user_receiver);
    }
    if (type == 'Listing Discrepancy') {
      $('#Operations1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'Manufacturing Discrepancy') {
      $('#Buyers1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'PO Discrepancy') {
      $('#Logistics1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'Receiving Discrepancy') {
      $('#Logistics1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'RMA Discrepancy') {
      $('#CustomerService1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'Sales Discrepancy') {
      $('#IT1').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (type == 'Shipping Discrepancy') {
      $('#Logistics').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var user_issue = $("#issue").val();
    var user_priority = $("#priority").val();
    var user_type = $("#type1").val();
    $.post("BugReport.php", {
      receiver: user_receiver,
      issue: user_issue,
      priority: user_priority,
      type1: user_type,
      receiver: user_receiver
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
    });
    document.getElementById('issue').value = '';
    $('#type1').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $('#priority').prop('selectedIndex', 1);
    $('#IT1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Operations1').css('display', 'block');
    $('#Logistics1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#CustomerService1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#Buyers1').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0000E6;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #58C6EB;
  width: 162px;
  height: 687px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.word {
  color: #0000E6;
}
.buttons {
  background-color: #CCFFFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <h3 class="word" style="margin:10px 30px 30px 30px;">Issue Report</h3>
  <div class="word" style="width: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">Type Of Issue:</div>
  <div style=" max-width: 150px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px">
    <form action="BugReport.php" method="post">
      <select class="buttons" name="type1" id="type1" style='max-width: 150px;'>
        <?php $servername="localhost" ; $username="user" ; $password="pass" ; $database="db" ; $con=m ysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database); if($con->connect_error){ die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error); } $sql1 = "select issue_name, issue_description from Issue"; $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $issue = $row['issue_name']; $des =
        $row['issue_description']; echo "
        <option value='$issue' title='$des'>$issue</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <form action="BugReport.phpl" method="post">
    <div id="Buyers1" style="display:none;">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="Buyers" id="Buyers" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = '1'" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="Operations1" style="display:block;">
    <form action="BugReport.php" method="post">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="Operations" id="Operations" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = 2" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="IT1" style="display:none;">
    <form action="BugReport.php" method="post">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="IT" id="IT" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = 3" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="CustomerService1" style="display:none;">
    <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="CustomerService" id="CustomerService" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = 4" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="HR1" style="display:none;">
    <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="HR" id="HR" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = 5" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Logistics1" style="display:none;">
    <form action="BugReport.html" method="post">
      <select class="buttons receiver" name="Logistics" id="Logistics" style="margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
        <?php $sql="select first, last from Employee where department_id = 6" ; $result=m ysqli_query($con,$sql); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($result)) { $name=$ row[ 'first'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last']; echo "<option value = '$name'>$name</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <form action="BugDisplayAndReply.html" method="post">
    <label></label>
    <br>
    <textarea style="max-width: 156px; background-color: #F3F9FF; border-color: #0000E6;" cols="20" rows="34" name="issue" id="issue" placeholder="Enter Your Issue Here" "></textarea></form><br>
       <div class="word " style="width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto ">Priority:</div>
       <div style = "width: 70px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px ">
       <form action="BugReport.html " method="post ">
       <select class = "buttons " name = "priority " id = "priority ">
        <option value = "Low ">Low</option>
        <option value = "Regular " selected>Regular</option>
        <option value = "High ">High</option>
        <option value = "Urgent ">Urgent</option>
       </select>
       </form></div>
      <div style = "width: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding: 2px ">
      <input class = "buttons " type ="submit " name = "sub " value = "Submit " id = "sub "></div>
      <div id="result "></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you several ways to shorten your code, but having the HTML would make it easier. Could you post it?

Comment: Can you show us some HTML too?  Also, you should use the .hide() and .show() functions not the .css functions.

Comment: Use `show()` and `hide()`

Comment: I posted it, i apologize for not cutting down the unimportant parts.  I've already figured out how to make the correct dropdown to appear, i just need help posting the value of the correct dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`jQuery(':visible')`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)?

(read the documentation about the performance implications!)